# Read a running log file in python and be able to create a output flag when a certain string or event occurs

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner to python but would like to read a large log file (monitor lines mostly at the end of the file when the events are being reported) and set a flag when a certain string or an event comes up.  I would like to use that flag to kick a relay using a ADU200 USB relay I/O interface controller.

Comment: Hello Felix, this is too vague. Please read the FAQ again. Do some research yourself, try stuff and when you have issues with your code you can ask more specifically. This isn't a place where you request free code from other people.

Comment: Okay, sorry I was not trying to get free code.  I will write my code that I think might work and then if I have any trouble with the code I will add to the question.